# need some amount of ether for getting the fake ether from alchemy

Tags: blockchain, metamask, goerli

actually i was trying to get the **goerliETH** on Goerli test network. when i visited Alchemy(https://goerlifaucet.com/) for same, it is asking for to have some amount of ETH in mainnet account i.e. proper message was "*To receive Goerli ETH, your wallet must have a minimum balance of 0.001 ETH on mainnet. Please add ETH to your wallet and try again*." But the problem is i actually **do not need real one**, i just **wants** to **have fake ether** for my school projects.
**Is anybody here who can send me some amount, so that i could get the fake ethers and i'll be really thankful to u.
my **Metamaask wallet** is : "**0xA7285aBeD11B0407415FFB8700AC597C4D0E76f0**"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you to shift to sepolia testnet instead because goerli is now deprecated. Here is the sepolia [faucet](https://sepoliafaucet.com/).

Yet if you want goerliETH, I have sent some to your given address. Here is the [txHash](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x2f98f3c576b76e70f9f580010ecaef1c491df861817344cc8a710b38ecd701d3)